# SQL Query to access database

Tags: c#, sql

I'm writing a database query that will show me where there is a space for parking. It is only used in July.

There is one table that shows all the spaces and whether they are rented that day. There is another table that has the spaces and their sizes. I want to be able to select those spaces that are available on all the days within the selected time period and have the correct size.

I am having a problem, though, selecting only the spaces available within the given time period. Here is the query so far but it does not contain anything concerning the space size as I want this part to work first.

```sql
  SELECT C.Plads, SUM[C.optaget] C.[ledlig] FROM
  (SELECT Plads FROM OptagetPladser AS A Inner JOIN Bådpladser as B ON  
  A.plads=B.Pladsnummer
  WHERE
  (A.dato>=" + Startdato + "and A.dato<="+Slutdato+") //checking the time period
  and (a.optaget = 0))                           //0 means the space is availible
  as C 
  GROUP BY C.Plads 
  HAVING SUM(C.optaget) >="+ diffResult+")";//diff result is the timespan
```

At the moment I'm getting the error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM[C.optaget]'

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace [] with () in SUM() expression :)

Comment: Which database? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL ... ?

Comment: Again, is this MS Access? SQL varies from version to version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should rework your SQL query - it contains too many simple errors.

Here are a few.

- Try adding a ',' and make some changes in query:

  `SELECT C.Plads, SUM(C.optaget), C.ledlig FROM`
- Your subquery `C` doesn't have an `optaget` and `ledlig` fields too. To fix this add those fields right after sebquery's `SELECT`
- Fix a syntax error here:

  `(A.dato>=" + Startdato + "and A.dato<="+Slutdato+")` which should be:

  `(A.dato >= " + Startdato + " and A.dato <= "+Slutdato+")`
- Your last double quote is redundant as well as last ')'. Remove it:

  `HAVING SUM(C.optaget) >= "+ diffResult+" ;//diff result is the timespan`

Below is how your SQL query should look. Please, note: there are still missing fields `optaget` and `ledlig` in subquery `C`.

```sql
SELECT C.Plads, SUM(C.optaget), C.ledlig FROM
(
    SELECT Plads FROM OptagetPladser AS A 
    INNER JOIN Bådpladser as B 
    ON A.plads = B.Pladsnummer
    WHERE (A.dato >= " + Startdato + " AND A.dato <= " + Slutdato + ")
      AND (a.optaget = 0)
)
AS C 
GROUP BY C.Plads 
HAVING SUM(C.optaget) >= " + diffResult + ";
```

I believe, there could appear an architectural or performance issues, but without table data I can't say it for sure.

Comment: SELECT C.Plads, SUM(C.optaget) FROM (SELECT Plads FROM OptagetPladser AS A Inner JOIN Bådpladser as B ON A.plads=B.Pladsnummer 
WHERE (A.dato>=" + Startdato + "and A.dato<="+Slutdato+") and (a.optaget = 0)) as C GROUP BY Plads HAVING SUM(optaget) >="+ diffResult+")

Comment: Ok, but you still have a few typos and syntax errors. Also, where is an `C.optaget` field? I assume, subquery `C` won't give you a `optaget` value other than 0, because of this condition: `AND (a.optaget = 0)`. More to say: you retrieve only `Plads` field from subquery, why so? I think, you should rewrite your query.
`

Comment: Can you give a detail table description and could you please give an English translation of tables names?

Comment: If this is MS Access, and from previous questions by the OP I suspect it is, you are likely to have problems with date formats.